# Lyx: How to align text

Tags: lyx

I don't know how to describe exactly my issue, but I'll make a try:

I am writing a document on Lyx, and I am using the module "report". I have customised the page margins but when I write paragraphs, some sentences do not obey the margin and some words are not in the same line. Graphically:

[image]

From a PDF that is created with Office there is a tool (a ruler I think) with which you can make the paragraphs in order to be all the words in the same line. For example:

[image]

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that TeX cannot find a good place to break the line. Unlike a word processor, TeX will overflow the edge of the page rather than produce a 'bad' linebreak. The idea is that you are then supposed to fix the issue.

Comment: What is hard to tell from your screenshots is, for example, whether you have set up LaTeX to use the correct hyphenation patterns for Greek (the English default ones clearly will not work!). A full answer therefore needs more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much , you helped me a lot

I forgot to change the language from English to Greek .. I am new on writing in Lyx and dont know a lot of things yet !!

Thanks again :)

Comment: @ALdaperan: I'm quite sure that LyX has a manual where you can look up such things.